# REMOVING REPEATED NUMBER FROM LIST, not working

Tags: python, list

I have written this code to remove repeating numbers from the list and output the max number. However, it is not removing the number which is repeated on the 4th index value. please help.

```
array = input()
nums = (array.split())
num = [int(i) for i in nums]

n = 0
for j in num:
 for q in num:
    if q == j:
        n += 1
    if n > 1:
        while j in num:
           num.remove(j)
    n = 0
print(num)
print(max(num))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)

Comment: You're removing elements from `num` while iterating over it, which doesn't work.

Comment: You could use a set if element order wasnt important

Comment: `code` array = input()

nums = (array.split())
num = [int(i) for i in nums]
final = [int(i) for i in nums]
n = 0
for j in num:
    for q in num:
        if q == j:
            n += 1
    if n > 1:
        while j in final:
            final.remove(j)
    n = 0
print(final)
if len(final) == 0:
    print(-1)
else:
    print(max(final))

Answer (score 1):

pythons build in function `set()` does this for you.

```
_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2]
print(set(_list))
```

outputs:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```